# How to encode a hash using Ruby Base64 module

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, base64, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to encode a hash and I am expecting it to return some value which I know. This is the ruby script I wrote to encode.

```
policy = {
 "expiration": "2015-12-30T12:00:00.000Z",
 "conditions": [
   {"bucket": "sigv4examplebucket"},
   ["starts-with", "$key", "user/user1/"],
   {"acl": "public-read"},
   {"success_action_redirect": "http://sigv4examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html"},
   ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/"],
   {"x-amz-meta-uuid": "14365123651274"},
   {"x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"},
   ["starts-with", "$x-amz-meta-tag", ""],
   {"x-amz-credential": "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE/20151229/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request"},
   {"x-amz-algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"},
   {"x-amz-date": "20151229T000000Z" }
 ]
}.to_s

enc = Base64.encode64(policy)
```

Expected encode value:

```
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
```

but my ruby script is returning:

```
ezpleHBpcmF0aW9uPT4iMjAxNS0xMi0zMFQxMjowMDowMC4wMDBaIiwgOmNvbmRpdGlvbnM9Plt7OmJ1Y2tldD0+InNpZ3Y0ZXhhbXBsZWJ1Y2tldCJ9LCBbInN0YXJ0cy13aXRoIiwgIiRrZXkiLCAidXNlci91c2VyMS8iXSwgezphY2w9PiJwdWJsaWMtcmVhZCJ9LCB7OnN1Y2Nlc3NfYWN0aW9uX3JlZGlyZWN0PT4iaHR0cDovL3NpZ3Y0ZXhhbXBsZWJ1Y2tldC5zMy5hbWF6b25hd3MuY29tL3N1Y2Nlc3NmdWxfdXBsb2FkLmh0bWwifSwgWyJzdGFydHMtd2l0aCIsICIkQ29udGVudC1UeXBlIiwgImltYWdlLyJdLCB7OiJ4LWFtei1tZXRhLXV1aWQiPT4iMTQzNjUxMjM2NTEyNzQifSwgezoieC1hbXotc2VydmVyLXNpZGUtZW5jcnlwdGlvbiI9PiJBRVMyNTYifSwgWyJzdGFydHMtd2l0aCIsICIkeC1hbXotbWV0YS10YWciLCAiIl0sIHs6IngtYW16LWNyZWRlbnRpYWwiPT4iQUtJQUlPU0ZPRE5ON0VYQU1QTEUvMjAxNTEyMjkvdXMtZWFzdC0xL3MzL2F3czRfcmVxdWVzdCJ9LCB7OiJ4LWFtei1hbGdvcml0aG0iPT4iQVdTNC1ITUFDLVNIQTI1NiJ9LCB7OiJ4LWFtei1kYXRlIj0+IjIwMTUxMjI5VDAwMDAwMFoifV19
```

When I used https://www.base64encode.org/, it returns exactly what is expected. I have taken the expected value from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html

Am I doing it right?

Comment: The value you expect is base64 encoding of a JSON like string with new lines.  But `to_s` on hash won't give you same string, hence, there is mismatch in output.

Answer (score 7):

You're expecting a pretty JSON string but you're getting a Ruby hash. This is closer to what you want:

```
Base64.encode64(JSON.dump(policy))
```

It's not exactly the same, not byte for byte, but should do the job.

If you need to get the output precisely the same you're going to have to wrangle around with JSON formatting even though the JSON is, data-wise, identical.

Comment: How is the '{' being encoded? Doesn't Base64 not support that character?

Comment: @Jwan622 Presumably as Base64, where `{}` encodes as `e30`. No actual `{` characters should appear in the Base64 *output*, you're right there, but the input is arbitrary, just binary bytes as far as Base64 is concerned.

Comment: I guess I'm misunderstanding something about converting characters to base64. How is it that '{' is converted to Base64 character e30?

Comment: @jwan622 As is usually the case [Wikipedia has a great overview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) of the subject.

Comment: @Jwan622 In Ruby: `Base64.encode64('{}')` This isn't some dark mystery, it's something you can experiment with. Virtually every language has a Base64 encoding method of some kind.

Answer (score 1):

Your `policy` holds a string representation of your hash in a single line like so:

```
{:expiration=>"2015-12-30T12:00:00.000Z", :conditions=>[{:bucket=>"sigv4examplebucket"}, ["starts-with", "$key", "user/user1/"], {:acl=>"public-read"}, {:success_action_redirect=>"http://sigv4examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html"}, ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/"], {:"x-amz-meta-uuid"=>"14365123651274"}, {:"x-amz-server-side-encryption"=>"AES256"}, ["starts-with", "$x-amz-meta-tag", ""], {:"x-amz-credential"=>"AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE/20151229/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request"}, {:"x-amz-algorithm"=>"AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"}, {:"x-amz-date"=>"20151229T000000Z"}]}
```

The "expected" base64 represents your hash formated:

```
{ "expiration": "2015-12-30T12:00:00.000Z",
  "conditions": [
    {"bucket": "sigv4examplebucket"},
    ["starts-with", "$key", "user/user1/"],
    {"acl": "public-read"},
    {"success_action_redirect": "http://sigv4examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html"},
    ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/"],
    {"x-amz-meta-uuid": "14365123651274"},
    {"x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"},
    ["starts-with", "$x-amz-meta-tag", ""],

    {"x-amz-credential": "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE/20151229/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request"},
    {"x-amz-algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"},
    {"x-amz-date": "20151229T000000Z" }
  ]
}
```

So, everything is working just fine.

Comment: I wouldn't say "working just fine," since the decided base64 needs to be valid json.

Comment: Well, that's a matter of calling `policy.to_json` and you'll get a valid json representation of the hash. My bad, I should have added that to my answer (+1).

Comment: PS. By "working just fine" I meant that those two strings are different, so the base64 representation must be different as well. So, everything is working just fine as it should.

Comment: Agreed, however, the base64 representation of the policy is going to be submitted to Amazon S3, which [expects to find JSON](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html), so while the encoding process itself is "working," the wrong thing is being encoded.