# Encode a Ruby hash using base64

Tags: json, ruby, base64

Trying to encode a hash using base64 but I couldn't get the expected base64 string.

```
json = {
  "v": "2",
  "ps": "法国",
  "add": "fr.sangyu.tw",
  "port": "443",
  "id": "ce14d788-0f79-491e-85ca-05240612f28a",
  "aid": "233",
  "net": "ws",
  "type": "none",
  "host": "fr.sangyu.tw",
  "path": "/",
  "tls": "tls"
}

Base64.encode64 JSON.dump(json)
```

Expected string:

`ew0KICAidiI6ICIyIiwNCiAgInBzIjogIuazleWbvSIsDQogICJhZGQiOiAiZnIuc2FuZ3l1LnR3IiwNCiAgInBvcnQiOiAiNDQzIiwNCiAgImlkIjogImNlMTRkNzg4LTBmNzktNDkxZS04NWNhLTA1MjQwNjEyZjI4YSIsDQogICJhaWQiOiAiMjMzIiwNCiAgIm5ldCI6ICJ3cyIsDQogICJ0eXBlIjogIm5vbmUiLA0KICAiaG9zdCI6ICJmci5zYW5neXUudHciLA0KICAicGF0aCI6ICIvIiwNCiAgInRscyI6ICJ0bHMiDQp9`

My (incorrect) string:

`eyJ2IjoiMiIsInBzIjoi5rOV5Zu9IiwiYWRkIjoiZnIuc2FuZ3l1LnR3Iiwi cG9ydCI6IjQ0MyIsImlkIjoiY2UxNGQ3ODgtMGY3OS00OTFlLTg1Y2EtMDUy NDA2MTJmMjhhIiwiYWlkIjoiMjMzIiwibmV0Ijoid3MiLCJ0eXBlIjoibm9u ZSIsImhvc3QiOiJmci5zYW5neXUudHciLCJwYXRoIjoiLyIsInRscyI6InRs cyJ9`

I saw the question [How to encode a hash using Ruby Base64 module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36724958/how-to-encode-a-hash-using-ruby-base64-module) but it didn't work for me.

Comment: How are you generating the expected string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do it correctly. There are a couple of reasons you don't get your expected output.

`JSON.dump(json)` generates the following (no formatting):

```
{"v":"2","ps":"","add":"fr.sangyu.tw","port":"443","id":"ce14d788-0f79-491e-85ca-05240612f28a","aid":"233","net":"ws","type":"none","host":"fr.sangyu.tw","path":"/","tls":"tls"}
```

You may want to use `JSON.pretty_generate(json)` which produce:

```
{
  "v": "2",
  "ps": "",
  "add": "fr.sangyu.tw",
  "port": "443",
  "id": "ce14d788-0f79-491e-85ca-05240612f28a",
  "aid": "233",
  "net": "ws",
  "type": "none",
  "host": "fr.sangyu.tw",
  "path": "/",
  "tls": "tls"
}
```

Lastly, I don't know which OS you are on or how you got your original expected `base64`, but they may have different line endings `\n` vs `\r\n`, which may cause different `base64`.

Comment: Do you mean changing `Base64.encode64 JSON.dump(json)` to `Base64.encode64 JSON.pretty_generate(json)` ? This still doesn't generate the expected string.

Comment: Another finding is that even if I decoded the base64 string (which I got from a API) using https://www.base64decode.org/, paste the result to https://www.base64encode.org/ and encode it, I get a different base64 string than the original one. Maybe it's because of the different line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use -

```
Base64.strict_encode64(JSON.pretty_generate(json))
```

The base64 string it generates is different from what you expect

```
ewogICJ2IjogIjIiLAogICJwcyI6ICLms5Xlm70iLAogICJhZGQiOiAiZnIuc2FuZ3l1LnR3IiwKICAicG9ydCI6ICI0NDMiLAogICJpZCI6ICJjZTE0ZDc4OC0wZjc5LTQ5MWUtODVjYS0wNTI0MDYxMmYyOGEiLAogICJhaWQiOiAiMjMzIiwKICAibmV0IjogIndzIiwKICAidHlwZSI6ICJub25lIiwKICAiaG9zdCI6ICJmci5zYW5neXUudHciLAogICJwYXRoIjogIi8iLAogICJ0bHMiOiAidGxzIgp9
```

But the content it generates are same.

Also I tried encoding your json in https://www.base64encode.org/ which generates the same string mentioned above in this answer.